# Some analysis concerning Levy-Kinchin-Formula (integral-identity)

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Let $$\psi_n(t) = \int \left(\exp(itx)-1\right)\nu_n(dx)$$ be the characteristic function of a C-Poisson distribution.
Defining 
$$ \psi(t) := \psi_n(t) -\frac{1}{2}\int_{t-1}^{t+1}\psi_n(s) \,ds $$
we get
$$ \psi(t) := \psi_n(t) -\frac{1}{2}\int_{t-1}^{t+1}\psi_n(s) \,ds $$
$$= \int \left(\exp(itx)-1\right)\nu_n(dx) - \frac{1}{2}\int_{t-1}^{t+1}\int \left(\exp(isx)-1\right)\nu_n(ds)$$
$$ \stackrel{!}{=} \int \exp(itx)\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^{1}\exp(isx)\,ds \right)\nu_n(dx)$$

I dont see the last identity. Can anybody help?